# How to handle delayed events with Drools Fusion

Tags: events, jboss, drools, complex-event-processing, drools-fusion

**Event A** then **Event B**. If there is **no Event B after 5 min of A** then trigger rule.

```
when 
  time1:Event() from entry-point xx 
  not (Event(this after[ 0,5m ] time1) from entry-point xx)
then 
 ... 
end
```

For realtime events that works fine, but in real life you have events coming in delayed, eg. from an interface.

Example: Event A time: 01:00 (mm:ss) but received at 02:00 Above rule will trigger at 07:00, but the business logic would require it to be triggered at 06:00

How do I handle this kind of requirement ?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a single answer to the problem, as there are different situations. The use case you presented here is easily fixed but simply using externally stamped timestamps. Assuming that your Event contains a property (e.g. datetime) that contains the timestamp when it happened at the source, you can tell the engine to use it as the timestamp of the event. E.g.:

```
declare Event
    @role( event )
    @timestamp( datetime )
end
```

In this case, then engine will use 01:00 as the event timestamp and the rule will fire at 06:00 (assuming no other event happened), even if event1 arrived at 02:00.

Comment: I believe (and tried) it does not work. I cant find any hint on this working. The documentation says something like events are immutable and 'you cant change the past'.